# How to make "Shift + Enter" generate a new line a text box?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, textbox, newline

I've seen some posts about making it in text area (which I'm not sure about the deiffernce between them both), but not sure how to make "Shift + Enter" generate a new line a text box.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't have multiple lines in a HTML textbox, the only way to do it is using the

```
<textarea></textarea>
```

tags

on the other hand for a c# textbox you can set the property:

```
Mytextbox.Multiline = true;
```

I hope my answer helped!